# how to enable auto completition of enviornment names or inturrupted commands in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

in texStudio I want the functionality of continued completion of commands after an interruption or a premature autocompletition

what happens
I start typing `\beg...`
it suggests `\begin{*enviornmentName*}` and I have to complete the whole word

what I want to happen:
now if I enter the parenthesis then it should continue to complete the environment.
Meaning right after completing `\begin{*enviornmentName*}` command by itself it should complete
`\begin{eq..}` to `\begin{equation}`

[image]

the above pic is of texMaker and I need it to work similarly in texStudio

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I seem to not see the question here...

Comment: @BMWurm the behavior i described is  partially done in texmaker I am not sure how to enable it in texstudio

Comment: @BMWurm I have edited the question may be its clearer now

Comment: I only have the german version installed so I don't really know the precise phrasing in english, but in the options menu, the first submenu should be the configuration menu. Once in there you can tick the box in the bottom left corner for advanced options to appear. afterwards you need to look on the left side for the "Completion" ["Vervollständigen"] menu, wherein you can switch on a lot of things, including choosing lists for words from specific packages texstudio should learn... which unfortunately can clutter the dropdown list, so use sparingly

Comment: @BMWurm German is no probs. I tried the cwl switching but I could not find the correct one after online research. As you can see I don't know the correct terminology to find it. Danke im Voraus

Comment: @BMWurm Bist du echt in KA ???? Ich auch :P

Comment: Yup :)  Cool :D ... *It's a small world...*

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see my configuration of TexStudio:

[image: My Configuration]

which seems to enable what you want it to do:
[image]

I am fairly certain, the most important one is the first and the "Typisch"

From the wordlists maybe ngerman.cwl and tex.cwl, although i am not using ams*.cwl and the proof environment is still available in dropdown (as seen above).

Comment: I tried switching yours on and some others as well I did not work so far. The functionality you are showing is without the second bracket(see my pic). That's the work around I use at the moment. I cannot use auto-completion for begin :D ... I know I am being lazy to type.

Comment: **Now** I get what you meant by *interrupted*, that doesn't work for me either, but if you switch the "Typisch" to "Bisher benutzt" you can just pick the one you need from the dropdown list. I am not sure TeXStudio can actually do this, maybe it has a simpler parser or something compared to TeXmaker?? Or somebody else might help :P I seem to recall someone on the site is on the TeXStudio team....

Comment: ja I did that already thanks for your help though

Comment: **Please note**: Usually it is *not* necessary to statically activate cwl files, see [the FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#when-are-cwl-files-loaded). Apart from that I'm not quite clear what your question is? Do you want to re-open the completer (`Idefix -> Complete -> Normal` (Ctrl+Space))?

Comment: @TimHoffmann I think that's it: `Ctrl`+`Space`, we'll see when OP returns.